# C - Reversing an int to an array

Tags: c

I'm trying to reverse the digits of an integer.
To do this I am:

1. Taking the integer.
2. Putting it into a string.
3. Putting the string into another string in reverse.
4. Converting the reversed string to a proper integer.

I've sort of gotten to step 3, and while it does reverse the string properly, it leaves me with a lot of odd data.
[image: The Results]
The top part is just the array lengths to compare.
What is happening for this odd data?

```
int ReverseNumber(int Num) {
//Variables
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
char Number[50];
char ReversedNumber[50];
sprintf(Number,"%d", Num);

//Finding Length Of Array
do{ 
    i++;
}while(Number[i] > 10);
//i - 1(Due to Array Length)
i--;

//Reverseing
do {
    printf("%d | %d \n",j,i);
    ReversedNumber[j] = Number[i];
    printf("%c\n", ReversedNumber[j]);
    getch();
    i--;
    j++;
} while (i != -1);

int NumberLength = (strlen(Number) - 1);
//Printing
printf("%s\n", Number);
printf("%s\n", ReversedNumber);
}
```

Comment: Why do you have this weird `do`/`while` loop to find the length of `Number` when you could just use `strlen`? And why do you later do `int NumberLength = (strlen(Number) - 1);` but never use `NumberLength`?

Comment: Your code doesn't terminate `ReversedNumber`.

Comment: Isn't this because you make An Array with lenght 50, C and C++ fill unused memory with strange objects as I remember correctly (been some time I programmed in C)

Comment: @StanFieuws C and C++ don't do that. It's the compiler that do that for debugging purpose. In MSVC [uninitialized memory will be filled with 0xCC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/370195/995714) and that's why `╠╠╠╠╠...` is seen (it's 0xCC in the [code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) which is the default in most PCs that use Western codepage)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc oke, thanks for clearing that up for me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `\0` to the end of `ReversedNumber`  after the reversing `do {...} while (...)` terminates:

```
//Reverseing
do {
...
} while (...);
ReversedNumber[j] = '\0';
```